# Convert 5 cells with 1s and 0s into a single array like {1,0,0,1,1} in Excel

Tags: excel

Alright, in excel I'm converting a 5 bit binary code into a single array in the form of a string. Cells D62, D64, D68, D70, and D72 all have either a 1 or a 0, and I'm requesting help to convert these cells with numbers in them into an array by using a formula. I need the output to cell D59.
`=IF(ARRAY(D62:D70)={1,1,1,0,0},1,0)`
something like that

Comment: In the form of a string? Concatenate with &, or CONCATENATE, or TEXTJOIN.

Comment: A cell cannot hold an array.  If you want a string that looks like an array then use TEXTJOIN or concatenate.  If you are going to use that array in another formula please tell us the end use so we can help.

Comment: Im converting say like 1 1 1 0 0 (in 5 different cells) into an IF statement, and IF D59 is equal to {1,1,1,0,0} then it would output G, because in 5 bit binary, G is 1 1 1 0 0

Comment: That's not making it much clearer, have a look at [ask] a question with a [mvce] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: ```=IF(D59={1,1,1,0,0},1,0)```

Comment: I thought `G` was `00111` not `11100`

Comment: well I'ts around that, its just reversed I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the 5 cells values to a 5 bit binary letter just concatenate:

```
=CHAR(BIN2DEC(A1&A2&A3&A4&A5)+64)
```

[image]

---

If one has CONCAT:

```
=CHAR(BIN2DEC(CONCAT(A1:A5))+64)
```

Answer (score 1):

In **D59** enter:

```
="{" & D62 & "," & D64 & "," & D68 & "," & D70 & "," & D72 & "}"
```

[image]